# Migrating Alamofire 4 on swift3 - Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

Tags: ios, swift3

I am migrating to swift 3 and so updated to Alamofire 4 and I am getting this error :

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

with this detail

```
.../Alamofire.framework/Alamofire compiled with older version of Swift language 
(2.0) than previous files (3.0) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my pod file:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
     end
  end
end
```

I do not know if it is linked, but I have also this warning when updating pods:

```
[!] The `MyProject [Release]` target overrides the
 `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target
Support Files/Pods-bbsigne/Pods-bbsigne.release.xcconfig'.
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
```

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Delete derived data of your project
2. Clean your project (Cmd+Shift+K)
3. Run `pod update` from terminal once again

To delete derived data in Xcode 8 do the following:

`File` -> `Workspace settings` -> Press arrow button next to the path -> Open `DerivedData` folder -> Delete folder starting with your project`s name

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. The problem is solved, I can run the project. I still have the warnings when updating pods.